# how to setup replication from on-premise MySQL to Azure PostgreSQL db

Tags: mysql, postgresql, azure, replication

Is it possible to replicate from on-premise MySQL to Azure PostgreSQL db? If yes, kindly suggest how to setup replication from on-premise MySQL to Azure PostgreSQL db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not quite replication, but you could set up an Azure Data Factory with an on-premise Integration Runtime and set up a pipeline to shift data between the two. This could work well for a one-way replication scenario. If you are looking to keep both databases in sync with updates, inserts and deletes on both sides, then there is nothing out of the box in Azure and you will need to look for a 3rd party product.

Answer (score 0):

Heterogenous replication can be performed by many third party replication solutions such as Striim or Attunity.  If you are looking at replication as part of a migration, you could also look into Azure Data Migration Services.